# Drawing a Number Scale with Circles above

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-graphdrawing

Is there an easy way to reproduce the following image in latex?
[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: Sure you can. Please don't be lazy next time ... or at least please post an address for billing you ;-)

Comment: I have seen a lot harder/greater questions than this that the OP at least has tried some things. How it is even possible to have 15-16 upvotes just to copy and paste a figure form somewhere and asking literally "do this for me?"... I do not understand here..

Comment: @MS-SPO, Onur Gürdoğan: You are right, but for about 4 years too late. The question already has three highly upvoted answers, and one was accepted. So I do not think you should close the question now. Sometimes questions like this just get through. I've made the title a little more descriptive to make the question at least a little better.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,
                positioning
                }
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 1pt and 0pt,
  start chain = going right,
 block/.style = {rectangle, minimum width=1.5em, outer sep=0pt,
                 on chain},
   dot/.style = {circle, fill, node contents={}}
                    ] 
\foreach \i in {0,...,14}{
    \node (n\i) [block] {\i};
                        }
\draw (n0.north west) -- (n14.north east);
\draw (n1.south west) -- ++ (0,-0.2) -| (n13.south east)
    node[pos=0.25,below] {$\text{Range} = 13 - 1 = 12$};
\node [dot,above=of n1];
\node [dot,above=of n2];
\node (d4) [dot,above=of n4];
\node [dot,above=of d4];
\node [dot,above=of n6];
\node (d8) [dot,above=of n8];
\node (d8a) [dot,above=of d8];
\node [dot, above=of d8a];
\node [dot, above=of n9];
\node (d11) [dot, above=of n11];
\node [dot, above=of d11];
\node [dot, above=of n12];
\node [dot, above=of n13];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum (1):**
you can define nodes styles for two and three dots. With them the code for picture is:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,
                positioning
                }
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 1pt and 0pt,
  start chain = going right,
 block/.style = {rectangle, minimum width=1.5em, outer sep=0pt,
                 on chain},
   dot/.style = {circle, fill, node contents={}},
  ddot/.style = {circle, fill, 
                 append after command={node[dot,above=of \tikzlastnode]},
                 node contents={}},
 dddot/.style = {circle, fill,
                 append after command={node (aux) [dot,above=of \tikzlastnode] 
                                       node [dot,above=of aux]},
                 node contents={}}
                    ] 
\foreach \i in {0,...,14}{
    \node (n\i) [block] {\i};
                        }
\draw (n0.north west) -- (n14.north east);
\draw (n1.south west) -- ++ (0,-0.2) -| (n13.south east)
    node[pos=0.25,below] {$\text{Range} = 13 - 1 = 12$};
%
\node [dot,above=of n1];
\node [dot,above=of n2];
\node [ddot,above=of n4];  % <---
\node [dot,above=of n6];
\node [dddot,above=of n8]; % <---
\node [dot, above=of n9];
\node [ddot, above=of n11];% <---
\node [dot, above=of n12];
\node [dot, above=of n13];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum (2):**
version with dots as labels in the loop. A bit shorter code:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,
                positioning
                }
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 1pt and 0pt,
  start chain = going right,
 block/.style = {rectangle, minimum width=1.5em, outer sep=0pt,
                 on chain},
   dot/.style = {circle, fill, node contents={}},
  ddot/.style = {circle, fill,
                 append after command={node[dot,above=of \tikzlastnode]}},
 dddot/.style = {circle, fill,
                 append after command={node (aux) [dot,above=of \tikzlastnode]
                                       node [dot,above=of aux]},
                 node contents={}}
                    ]
\foreach \i [count=\j from 0] in { , dot, dot, ,ddot,    , dot, 
                                   ,dddot,dot, ,ddot, dot, dot, }{
    \node (n\j) [block, label={[yshift=3pt,\i]}] {\j};
                        }
\draw (n0.north west) -- (n14.north east);
\draw (n1.south) -- ++ (0,-0.1) -| (n13.south)
    node[pos=0.25,below] {$\text{Range} = 13 - 1 = 12$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result is the same as before.

Comment: "Result is the same" except you corrected an error (the too-short bar below). Excellent!

Comment: @user3445853, almost the same ... :-), recently I experiences some difficulties to upload images, so I didn't provide the recent one :-( (which not differ very much from showed)

Answer (score 31):

Use `pic`s. You can define a `pic` `tower list` which draws the circles. Getting all the x coordinates and circles is then as simple as saying

```
 \pic{tower list={0,1,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,1,0,2,1,1,0}};
```

where the integers indicate how many circles should be drawn at 0, 1, 2....

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily,pics/tower/.style={code={
\ifnum#1>0
\foreach \X in {1,...,#1}{\fill (0,\X*0.4) circle[radius=0.17cm];}
\fi}},
pics/tower list/.style={code={\path foreach \Y [count=\Z starting from 0] in {#1}
{ (\Z*0.5,0)node[below](tower-\Z){$\mathsf{\Z}$} (\Z*0.5,0) pic{tower=\Y}};}}]
 \begin{scope}
  \pic{tower list={0,1,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,1,0,2,1,1,0}};
  \draw (tower-0.west|-0,0) -- (tower-13.east|-0,0);
  \draw[blue] (tower-1.south) -- ++(0,-0.1) 
  -| (tower-13.south) 
  node[pos=0.25,below]{Range${}=\mathsf{13}-\mathsf{1}=\mathsf{12}$};
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello, then with such a technique you can built an Italian abacus with units, tens, hundreds? +1. Can I ask a question on LaTeX with reference to your code?

Comment: @Sebastiano Sure you can define an abacus pic (will be back in a bit...)

Answer (score 18):

You don't really need TiKZ for this. Just `marvosym, booktabs` and `stackengine`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage[svgnames, table]{xcolor}
\newcommand\MVTen{\MVOne\MVZero}
\newcommand\MVxi{\MVOne\MVOne}
\newcommand\MVxii{\MVOne\MVTwo}
\newcommand\MVxiii{\MVOne\MVThree}
\newcommand\MVxiv{\MVOne\MVFour}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}

\begin{document}

\setstackgap{S}{0pt}
\begin{tabular}{*{15}{c}}
& \CircSteel & \CircSteel & & \Shortstack{\CircSteel\\ \CircSteel} & & \CircSteel & & \Shortstack{\CircSteel\\ \CircSteel\\ \CircSteel} & \CircSteel & & \Shortstack{\CircSteel\\ \CircSteel} & \CircSteel & \CircSteel \\[-0.6ex]
\midrule[1pt]
\MVZero & \MVOne & \MVTwo & \MVThree & \MVFour & \MVFive & \MVSix & \MVSeven & \MVEight & \MVNine & \MVTen & \MVxi & \MVxii & \MVxiii & \MVxiv \\[-1ex]
\arrayrulecolor{LightSlateBlue!60} &\color{LightSlateBlue!60} \rule{1pt}{1.3ex} & \multicolumn{11}{c}{} & \color{LightSlateBlue!60}\rule{1pt}{1.3ex} \\[-1.46ex]
\cmidrule[1pt](l{0.88em}r{1.19em}){2-14}\addlinespace[-0.3ex]
& \multicolumn{13}{c}{\sffamily\bfseries Range = 13 – 1 = 12}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Edit: I found them on CTAN :).  Can you give a brief explanation of the packages you have mentioned? (because the names seems similar with the word abacus.)